# PHP - basic array merge

Tags: php, arrays

This is basic, but for some reason its stumping me!

I wish to have an array structured:

```
    Array
(
    [0][product] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 128160
            [product_score] => 5
        )

    [1][product] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 128161
            [product_score] => 5
        )

    [2][product] => Array
            (
                [product_id] => 128162
                [product_score] => 5
            )

    )
```

etc.

But I cannot seem to push to this correctly,

```
$productArr['product'] = array("product_id" => $product_id,"product_score" => $score);

$savedProducts = array_merge($savedProducts, $productArr);
```

gives me:

```
Notice: Undefined index: product
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: $savedProducts[]['product'] = $productArr['product'];

Comment: I think all you need to do for your array structure is `$savedProducts[]=$productArr`

Comment: how is it possible to have to indexes? [2][product] 
Please paste correctly your array

Comment: @Pian0_M4n I guess he didn't show us the `var_dump` output but just an example how he wants his array to look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a notice. It most possibly means you didn't define the `product` index. I guess you're defining the `$productArr` on the fly. Maybe you want to do it like this:

```
$productArr = array(
    'product' => array("product_id" => $product_id,"product_score" => $score)
);
```

Then:

```
array_push($savedProducts, $productArr);
// or ever more simple
$savedProducts[] = $productArr;
```

Answer (score 3):

you have to use the array_push function

$productArr['product'] = array("product_id" => $product_id,"product_score" => $score);

array_push($savedProducts, $productArr);

http://php.itronic.at/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
$productArr[]['product'] = array("product_id" => $product_id,"product_score" => $score);
```

An then merge it or store it in whatever other var you want but be careful. you are merging multi-level arrays, you need recursive merging. This will do the trick:

```
function merge_r ( &$array1, &$array2 ){
             if (self::is($array1)  && !self::is($array2)) return $array1;
        else if (!self::is($array1) && self::is($array2))  return $array2;
        else if (!self::is($array1) && !self::is($array2)) return;
        else if (self::is($array1) && self::is($array2)) {
            $merged = $array1;
     foreach ( $array2 as $key => &$value )  {
       if ( self::is ( $value ) && isset ( $merged [$key] ) && self::is ( $merged [$key] ))    
        $merged [$key] = array_merge_r ( $merged [$key], $value );    
        else $merged [$key] = $value;
         }    
      }
   return $merged;
}
```

Then merge:
$savedProducts = merge_r($savedProducts, $productArr);

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
$savedProducts[] = $prodArray;
```

and

```
array_push($savedProducts,$prodArray);
```

will work, but the [PHP-Manual](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) tells us to prefer the first solution in this case, since it requires one less function call.